# Hive 3.1+ doesn't deserialize Avro 1.8.3+ messages from Kafka 1.0+

Tags: hive, apache-kafka, hiveql, avro, confluent-platform

Lets say I have topic created via kafka streams from Confluent which contains messages serialized in avro with `io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerializer`

Then I create an external kafka table in Hive

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE k_table
(`id` string , `sequence` int) 
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.kafka.KafkaStorageHandler' 
TBLPROPERTIES 
( 
  "kafka.topic" = "sample-topic", 
  "kafka.bootstrap.servers"="kafka1:9092", 
  "kafka.serde.class"="org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe", 
  "avro.schema.url"="Sample.avsc"
```

);

When I run the query:

```
select * from k_table WHERE `__timestamp` >  1000 * to_unix_timestamp(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - interval '2' DAYS)
```

I got unexpected IO error:

```
INFO  : Executing command(queryId=root_20190205160129_4579b5ff-9a5c-496d-8d03-9a7ccc0f6d90): select * from k_tickets_prod2 WHERE `__timestamp` >  1000 * to_unix_timestamp(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - interval '1' minute)
INFO  : Completed executing command(queryId=root_20190205160129_4579b5ff-9a5c-496d-8d03-9a7ccc0f6d90); Time taken: 0.002 seconds
INFO  : Concurrency mode is disabled, not creating a lock manager
Error: java.io.IOException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 55 (state=,code=0)
```

Well all works fine with Confluent kafka consumer and also I tried to set confluent kafka deserializer in `TBLPROPERTIES` which seems to have to effect.

Environment:

```
Hive 4.0 + Beeline 3.1.1 + Kafka 1.1 (Clients & Broker) + Confluent 4.1
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is Confluent producer serializes avro messages with custom format as `<magic_byte 0x00><4 bytes of schema ID><regular avro bytes for object that conforms to schema>`. So Hive kafka handler has problem to deserialize cuz it uses basic bytearray kafka deserializer and these 5 bytes at the beginning of the message are unexpected.

I've created a [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-21218) in hive to support Confluent format and Schema registry as well and also I've made a [PR with quick fix](https://github.com/apache/hive/pull/526) that removes 5 bytes from message after `"avro.serde.magic.bytes"="true"` property is set in `TBLPROPERTIES`.

After this patch it works like charm.

Comment: Hive does support `avro.schema.url`, though, so rather than skip, you could extract and use that ID

Comment: Well this is misleading. It supports `avro.schema.url` so you can download avsc file form S3 or HTTP but it doesn't `schema registry` and there are still these magic bytes from `io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerializer` that makes deserialization with hive `org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe`  impossible.

Comment: Correct, you cannot use `org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe`, but that doesn't prevent one from adding their own SerDe on the Hive classpath (rather than patching the Hive Avro one that expects the embdedded schema)